# How to disable the PhpStorm debugger cues from appearing

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I don't know how I enabled this feature, but I can't seem to get rid of it. Every time I click a button in the debugger that little window appears, and flashes for a few seconds. It looks like an accessibility feature, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Any suggestions?

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be one of the 3rd party (not bundled) plugins.

Go to `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Plugins` and browse through descriptions of all non-bundled plugins. Quite possibly it is a **Key Promoter** plugin.